# NoClassDefFoundError when trying to login with facebook

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm trying to implement login with Facebook in my unity app but when I'm calling FB.LogInWithReadPermissions I'm getting the following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.applinks.AppLinkData

StackTrace:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.applinks.AppLinkData at
> libcore.reflect.InternalNames.getClass(InternalNames.java:55) at
> java.lang.Class.getDexCacheType(Class.java:2551) at
> java.lang.reflect.AbstractMethod.getParameterTypes(AbstractMethod.java:169)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.getParameterTypes(Method.java:193) at
> java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1812) at
> com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.getMethodID(Unknown Source) at
> com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method) at
> com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.access$300(Unknown Source) at
> com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source) at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at
> com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "com.facebook.applinks.AppLinkData" on path: DexPathList[[zip file

My code:

```
public void facebookLogin()
 {
     try
     {
         facebookButton.interactable = false;
         var perms = new List<string>() { "public_profile", "email" };
         FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(perms, (result) =>
         {
             if (result.Cancelled)
             {
                 facebookButton.interactable = true;
             }
             else if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
             {
                 var aToken = Facebook.Unity.AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
                 Dictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                 {
                 { "accessToken", aToken.TokenString }
                 };
             //
             managers.server.loginWithFacebook(data, (succ, error) =>
                 {
                     if (succ)
                     {
                         showHome();
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         facebookButton.interactable = true;
                         showError(error, () => { });
                     }
                 });
             }
             else
             {
                 facebookButton.interactable = true;
             }
         });
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Debug.Log(ex);
     }
 }
```

Unity Editor Version: 2020.3.15f1
Facebook SDK Version: 11.0.0

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError appears when it fails to find .class file of java class.

as the class file is not present you cant access any function or variable from that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to update the [unity-jar-resolver](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver)
and then running resolve (Assets> External Dependency Manager> Android Resolver> Resolve)